# Problems Accessing MS Word 2010 with Python

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

I am using Python with Eclipse. I need to access MS Word file with Python. I have seen some examples on this and I have already installed pywin32. I tried some of the examples but I am getting some errors.

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("myfile.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
print doc.Content.Text
word.Quit()
```

This is the error I am getting. It would be great if anyone can tell me what I did wrong here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dino\Desktop\Python27\Test\src\AccessWordDoc.py", line 10, in <module>
    word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

Is there another way to access the MS word file and extract the data in it without going through all this?

Comment: Consider: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: @Torxed - Will it work for MS Word 2010 version. I am more than willing to consider any option at this point.

Comment: It will, as long as the document is saved as `*.docx` and not the old `*.doc` format. Check my answer below, and check the registry key-value for Word and you can hook to Word if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The win32 api for calling system api's is great and all but it is a chore.
If you're open for the idea and you know you'll be accessing the newer document format by windows (based on XML), that is `.docx` i'd suggest using a native module such as [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

There's no reason for using the pyWin32 module unless you're going to some very specific tasks.

There's also alternatives for Excel, such as [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/)

As to your original problem, i'm guessing that the `Word` you're hooking against is not actually `Microsft Word 2013` but rather an unknown or missing application.

Quote [Link](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2004-May/001947.html) (This describes youre issue and validates my guess that `Word.Application` is not actually an application)

> You are trying to use a ProgID that does not exist.  A "ProgID" is
>   really just a mapping to its CLSID.  It sounds like your object is not
>   registering itself correctly.
>
> Look in the registry - all COM objects have their name directly under
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Under that name, you will find a CLSID.  This
>   CLSID will then have a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID.  Look at the
>   registry to confirm that the names you tried do not exist as COM
>   objects.
>
> Otherwise, try using the CLSID of the object directly, instead of the
>   ProgID - just pass the IID string directly to Dispatch()

I checked my registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\` and searched for Word standing on that Key (folder). I got:

Key: `{00020-0000-0000-0000-00000-0000}` **titled**: `Microsoft Word Document`
with a sub-folder called `ProgID`, with the value: `Word.Document.8`
Which would let me to do:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Document.8")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("myfile.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
print doc.Content.Text
word.Quit()
```

Now, this is an older version of Word, since i don't have Word 2013 or even something fancy as 2010 :) Or i could just enter the KEY which would be `00020-000....` (i think).

A neat lazy-mans workaround [Video tutorial here](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?fromSeriesID=7&name=UsingpyWinAutoToControlAWindowsApplication):

Comment: I am trying to open Word file in python to extract some data. I would not mind if I could convert the .docx file into something python can manipulate as long as I can get the date from the file.

Comment: Python can manipulate docx with that given module i linked at the very beginning.

Comment: @Cryssie Btw, if you're willing to open and convert the document (Against all logic or programming...) you can just donvert it to a plain text document (*.txt)?

Comment: I believe your method should work but unfortunately I am using MS Office Starter 2010 and I wasn't able to find the correct registry value to pass through.

Comment: To bad, try going for the `docx` module to grab your data :) Good luck with your endeavors!

Answer (score 2):

The code below worked for me, which is just a simple change of "Word.Application" to "Word.Application.8":

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application.8")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("myfile.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument
print doc.Content.Text
word.Quit()
```

I came to this solution following @Torxed's suggestion to examine the registry. When I tried Word.Document.8, the set of methods available did not include .Visible, .Quit, and .Open and so @Torxed's solution did not work for me. (It is clear now that the Application and Word objects are intended to have different uses.) Instead, I also found Word.Application, Word.Application.8, and Word.Application.14 under my registry and just tried Word.Application.8 and it worked as expected.