# win32com opening Word

Tags: python, win32com

I am using win32 client to open a microsoft word document. I would like to convert word version to 2016 and I am encountering error

```
from win32com import client
import pythoncom
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Open(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<filepath>\test.docx')
doc.Convert()
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

and I am having this error from `word.Documents.open`

````
    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024703, 'OLE error 0x800700c1', None, None)```
````

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error says Microsoft word document is not installed in your system.

Comment: Hmm thats weird because it is installed

Comment: Then I think its a problem with version. refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226090/problems-accessing-ms-word-2010-with-python